# PhD: Accepted into another PhD program - should I finish the current semester in my old program?

Tags: phd, transfer-student

As the title says - I've been accepted into another (better) PhD program that is far more aligned with my interests and will be a better place for my dissertation; should I finish out my current semester of doctoral coursework or just take the "W"s and be done with it (only my 3rd semester, not ABD yet)? I don't need these credits in my new program; further, finishing this semester is going to be a PAIN and will probably negatively effect my perfect GPA (it's a heavier than normal load + I got behind in applying to my new program). Will withdrawing mid-semester (I'm still within the window for properly doing so) have unforeseen consequences?

Thoughts? Advice? Public Bludgeoning?

Comment: I don't think anyone cares about GPAs in phd programs.

Comment: If two candidates are otherwise equal, wouldn't the one with higher GPA be perceived as slightly "better"? After all, it atleast shows sincerity and diligence with various evaluation modules.

Comment: Check if the offer conditional on successful completion of your current courses. This is sometimes the case!

Answer (score 1):

You got a high GPA so you might have a better chance of getting into a Phd program.

You already got accepted into the program of your choice, so at the moment your GPA is useless.

Your only consideration should be when you want to start, if you like the courses so much that you'd take them for general interest, and if you want to do something after your Phd where GPA suddenly counts again (instead of publications / references).